# Substantiate that polars isn't copying data even though python reports different id

Tags: python, dataframe, python-polars

If I have two tables A and B, how can I do a join of B into A in place so that A keeps all its data and is modified by that join without having to make a copy?
And can that join only take specified columns from B into A?

A:

```
┌─────┬─────┬───────┐
│ one ┆ two ┆ three │
╞═════╪═════╪═══════╡
│ a   ┆ 1   ┆ 3     │
│ b   ┆ 4   ┆ 6     │
│ c   ┆ 7   ┆ 9     │
│ d   ┆ 10  ┆ 12    │
│ e   ┆ 13  ┆ 15    │
│ f   ┆ 16  ┆ 18    │
└─────┴─────┴───────┘
```

B:

```
┌─────┬─────┬───────┬──────┐
│ one ┆ two ┆ three ┆ four │
╞═════╪═════╪═══════╪══════╡
│ a   ┆ 1   ┆ 3     ┆ yes  │
│ c   ┆ 7   ┆ 9     ┆ yes  │
│ f   ┆ 16  ┆ 18    ┆ yes  │
└─────┴─────┴───────┴──────┘
```

I'd like to left join A and B, keeping all data in A and the `four` column of B - renamed as result.

With data.table I can do exactly this after reading A and B:

```r
address(A)
# [1] "0x55fc74197910"

A[B, on = .(one, two), result := i.four]
A

#    one two three result
# 1:   a   1     3    yes
# 2:   b   4     6   <NA>
# 3:   c   7     9    yes
# 4:   d  10    12   <NA>
# 5:   e  13    15   <NA>
# 6:   f  16    18    yes

address(A)
# [1] "0x55fc74197910"
```

With polars in python:

```py
A.join(B, on = ["one", "two"], how = 'left')

# shape: (6, 5)
# ┌─────┬─────┬───────┬─────────────┬──────┐
# │ one ┆ two ┆ three ┆ three_right ┆ four │
# │ --- ┆ --- ┆ ---   ┆ ---         ┆ ---  │
# │ str ┆ i64 ┆ i64   ┆ i64         ┆ str  │
# ╞═════╪═════╪═══════╪═════════════╪══════╡
# │ a   ┆ 1   ┆ 3     ┆ 3           ┆ yes  │
# │ b   ┆ 4   ┆ 6     ┆ null        ┆ null │
# │ c   ┆ 7   ┆ 9     ┆ 9           ┆ yes  │
# │ d   ┆ 10  ┆ 12    ┆ null        ┆ null │
# │ e   ┆ 13  ┆ 15    ┆ null        ┆ null │
# │ f   ┆ 16  ┆ 18    ┆ 18          ┆ yes  │
# └─────┴─────┴───────┴─────────────┴──────┘


A

# shape: (6, 3)
# ┌─────┬─────┬───────┐
# │ one ┆ two ┆ three │
# │ --- ┆ --- ┆ ---   │
# │ str ┆ i64 ┆ i64   │
# ╞═════╪═════╪═══════╡
# │ a   ┆ 1   ┆ 3     │
# │ b   ┆ 4   ┆ 6     │
# │ c   ┆ 7   ┆ 9     │
# │ d   ┆ 10  ┆ 12    │
# │ e   ┆ 13  ┆ 15    │
# │ f   ┆ 16  ┆ 18    │
# └─────┴─────┴───────┘
```

A is unchanged. If A is assigned again:

```
id(A)
# 139703375023552

A = A.join(B, on = ['one', 'two'], right_on=["four"])
id(A)

# 139703374967280
```

its memory address changes.

Comment: Are you inferring that the change in address means it's copying or do you have some reason for wanting the address of the pointer to stay the same?

Comment: Yes I'm assuming there's a copy happening and that that's a performance hit. Would that not be the case?

Comment: No, check this https://youtu.be/XAU3dUjaX38?t=869

Comment: Then is there a way to join and return a subset of the columns instead of all of them? Or would I need to remove the columns I don't want after the join?

Comment: Since the join is changing the dataframe wouldn't there be a copy of the full dataset for every join?

Comment: I don't think so.  Hopefully @ritchie46 comes by to end the uncertainty.  In the meantime the test is to load up something that takes up most of your ram and then do operations that might copy.  If it crashes then it's copying .  If it's not crashing then it's not copying.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is indeed no copy occurring there; if you think of the `DataFrame` class as a container (like a python list), you can see the same sort of thing happening here - the *container* id changes, but the *contents* of the container are not copied:

```py
# create a list/container with some object data
v1 = [object(), object(), object()]
print(v1)
# [<object at 0x1686b6510>, <object at 0x1686b6490>, <object at 0x1686b6550>]

v2 = v1[:]
print(v2)
# [<object at 0x1686b6510>, <object at 0x1686b6490>, <object at 0x1686b6550>]

v3 = v1[:2]
print(v3)
# [<object at 0x1686b6510>, <object at 0x1686b6490>]
```

(Each of `v1`, `v2`, and `v3` will have different ids).

Comment: I think that makes sense. However, the join done with pypolars takes twice the time that data.table takes? Is there a better way to do this join?

Comment: @basesorbytes try with large dataframes/data.table rather than tiny ones.  For instance, check out [these benchmarks](https://h2oai.github.io/db-benchmark/)

Comment: I'm working with quite a large dataset: 28m rows x 20 cols